# Separator in middle of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, rules

How can I put some kind of separator, (say horizontal line or `tikz` edge), mid way through the table of contents to break the Table of Contents into distinct blocks for frontmatter, mainmatter and backmatter.

Comment: See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1063/5764

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adjust the spacing as preferred:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20pt}\hrule\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20pt}\hrule\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
\backmatter
\chapter{\bibname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can make it automatic, say with

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\newcommand{\tocseparator}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}
    {\protect\addvspace{20pt}%
     \hrule
     \protect\addvspace{10pt}%
    }%
}
\preto\mainmatter{\tocseparator}
\preto\backmatter{\tocseparator}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}

\backmatter
\chapter{\bibname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Cheers.